# Why can I not find a foreign key using the OBJECT_ID() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a strange issue in MS SQL Server 2012.  I'm trying to check if a foreign key already exist in an upgrade script.  I've used the system OBJECT_ID() function in the past to find tables, views and procedures, but when I try to use it to find a foreign key it does not work.

```
-- This query always returns null
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'FK_Name', N'F')

-- This query works, returning the object ID for the foreign key
SELECT object_id FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE name=N'FK_Name'
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186918/159429) SO answer suggests that my OBJECT_ID() query should work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well it could be that your foreign key is looking to the table not in default schema (probably `dbo`). In this case you'll not see `object_id` until you specify schema, like this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'<schema>.FK_Name', N'F')
```

Actually, you could have multiple objects with the same name in your database, but within different schemas. `OBJECT_ID(N'FK_Name', N'F')` will return id of object in the default schema.

You can test it like this:

```
create schema test
create table test.temp1 (id int primary key)
create table test.temp2 (id int)
go

alter table test.temp2 add constraint FK_temp foreign key(id) references test.temp1(id)

select object_id('FK_temp', 'F')  -- returns null
select object_id('test.FK_temp', 'F') -- returns object id

drop table test.temp2
drop table test.temp1
drop schema test
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0059/1)</kbd>**

Comment: FK belongs to objects, and objects belongs to schema

Comment: Did I miss something, why -1?

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  Adding the schema before the FK name fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: One thing to add to this post - if the foreign key name contains a full stop (.) character, you must place the schema and name in square brackets i.e.  [schema].[name]